# What are common causes of --runInBand causing failures in jest tests?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, sinon, mobx

I tried running **--runInBand** with my jest tests and it's causing lots of tests to fail. Is there a common issue around this. I'm sure my tests are leaky but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: It's funny you mention this because a colleague of mine has been debugging that recently. Our problem was that we were assigning mocks to global functions like `matchMedia` so each time a component was rendered that used that, jest would store bunch of a junk for it. You have anything like that in your app?

Comment: @TomFinney I don't see too much global mocks like what you have mentioned but we do have some global utils that I'm suspicious of.

Comment: Try making them all something really dumb and then see if you get the same memory issues?

Comment: @TomFinney that's definitely a way to go about it. I'm going to mark as resolved for now, but hopefully if anyone else has seen this issue before as well.

Comment: I'm not using any mock at all in my project and it still fails with a single worker...